# docker run won't work but docker compose work fine

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

i try to run fastapi application with docker
i create this Dockerfile

```
FROM python

WORKDIR /code

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/

RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

COPY . /code/

CMD ["uvicorn", "blog.main:app"]
```

and run it with

```
docker run -p 8000:8000
```

the log says the application run on 127.0.0.1:8000 but i can't access the application on http://localhost:8000

i create docker compose like this

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: uvicorn blog.main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

and remove the **CMD** from *Dockerfile* and again have same log message **application running at 127.0.0.1:8000** but this time i can access my application via http://localhost:8000

can someone explain whats wrong with my first method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In docker-compose you are overriding the `CMD` with correct way of exposing the `host` and port to outside world.  In your Dockerfile change `CMD ["uvicorn", "blog.main:app"]` to `CMD ["uvicorn", "blog.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0",  "--port",  "8000"]` docker run should work

Comment: tnx i will check it

Comment: (...and then you can delete the `command:` override from the Compose file.)

Answer (score 1):

You do not want the application listening on 127.0.0.1:8000.  You want it listening on 0.0.0.0:8000 (as the second version is).  I am not familiar with the program you are running, but there must be some way to tell it the host to listen on.

When a server binds to localhost (127.0.0.1), it accepts connections only from that machine.  (The client also has to use localhost, not the actual IP address.) Since to docker, the host machine is a different machine, the connection is not allowed.